# In React Paginate, why there are multiple ul's rendering instead of showing me the page numbers?

Tags: javascript, debugging, next.js, nft, react-paginate

I am working on Next.js project. I have implemented React Paginate ( ^8.2.0 ) at a place. [React Pagination Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBCK6.png).

Here's the code :

```
<ReactPaginate
                previousLabel={"Previous"}
                nextLabel={"Next"}
                breakLabel={"..."}
                pageCount={filteredNftData?.totalPages}
                marginPagesDisplayed={1}
                pageRangeDisplayed={2}
                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                containerClassName={"pagination"}
                subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                activeClassName={"active"}
                forcePage={pageNum - 1}
              />
```

This is where i am getting the array of filteredNftData :
`const filteredNftData = showNotMinted ? notMintedNftCardData : nftCardData;`

This is from where i am calling these API's :

```
  const getwishlistApi = async (nextrprev, isMinted = false) => {
    let walletAddress;
    !account.address ? (walletAddress = "") : (walletAddress = account.address);
    try {
      let result = await getNftCards(categoryName, pageNum, walletAddress, isMinted);
      setNotMintedNftCardData(result);
      if (nextrprev) {
        tabsRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "start",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
    try {
      let result = await getNftCards(categoryName, pageNum, walletAddress);
      setNftCardData(result);
      if (nextrprev) {
        tabsRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "start",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };
```

These are the states in which i am getting data :

```
  const [nftCardData, setNftCardData] = useState([]);
  const [notMintedNftCardData, setNotMintedNftCardData] = useState([]);
```

Why am i facing this issue : [React Pagination Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBCK6.png).

I am expecting this : [Correct output on npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQEdj.png). But it's not showing expected response on npm start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.